# Is default IDE important for use git? Or it doesnt matter for usage?

Tags: git, ide

I am using different IDEs for different languages in different PCs. I want to use Git for syncs projects PC to PC. Is default IDE important for use git? Or it doesnt matter for usage?

Comment: Git does not come with an IDE. (Git does come with a GUI, `git-gui`, but it's quite klunky and should not be used: the people who wrote it don't use it themselves.) People who like IDEs like them, and probably should use them. People who hate IDEs—including me—hate them and probably shouldn't use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what IDEs you mean. In general it's not important because Git is just a version control system and it will save what code you upload. Note that Git can also be used locally. You don't need GitHub or some other services to have a git repository.

There are some things that are better with the same IDE.
IDE's like IntelliJ etc. have an Auto Formatter, which may conflict with other Auto Formatters like Visual Studio Code's.
These conflicts are not breaking your code, but it will produce a lot of changes in files as you are opening them in different IDEs and will run the Auto Formatter.
For example: You change 3 Lines of Code, but the whole file got auto formatted by another IDE and the total changes are 200 Lines.

Comment: I am using PyCharm for python and IntelliJ for java.

Comment: As you are using them in 2 different projects I assume, it doesn't matter. :) The example I meant is if you use 2 different IDEs with the same project. I once had formatting conflicts with WebStorm and VSCode.

Comment: Thanks! It's realy helpful :D